# Administrator com_plugins issue/bug (?) - Error Column 'type' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: joomla-3.x, bugs, com-plugins

On a site that I have been working on for a long time, I suddenly came across this issue. When I went to com_plugins to change settings on my plugins, I got the error below and the plugins list didn't show.

> Error
>
> **Column 'type' in where clause is ambiguous**
>
> SQL=SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `#__extensions` AS a LEFT JOIN #__users AS uc ON
>   uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN #__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access
>   WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0
>
> **Column 'type' in where clause is ambiguous**
>
> SQL=SELECT a.extension_id ,
>   a.name, a.element, a.folder, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time,
>   a.enabled, a.access, a.ordering,uc.name AS editor,ag.title AS
>   access_level FROM `#__extensions` AS a LEFT JOIN #__users AS uc ON
>   uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN #__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access
>   WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0
>   ORDER BY `folder` asc,a.ordering ASC LIMIT 0, 20
>
> **Column 'type' in
>   where clause is ambiguous**
>
> SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `#__extensions` AS
>   a LEFT JOIN #__users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out LEFT JOIN #__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access WHERE `type` = 'plugin' AND (a.enabled IN (0, 1)) AND a.state >= 0

The `where type= 'plugin'` clause is ambiguous. 
I checked the plugins model of the com_plugins in a clean joomla installation, as well as in a few older versions of J3. The part of the code in question is at about line 211, in the `getListQuery()` method.

```
// Select the required fields from the table.
    $query->select(
        $this->getState(
            'list.select',
            'a.extension_id , a.name, a.element, a.folder, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time,' .
                ' a.enabled, a.access, a.ordering'
        )
    )
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions') . ' AS a')
        ->where($db->quoteName('type') . ' = ' . $db->quote('plugin'));
```

All installations come like this and the strange thing is that it was always working fine in any Joomla site, but suddenly not on this one.

Running the same query directly in Joomla databases, it works for other Joomla db installations but not on this one, where it also gives the same error about the ambiguous column 'type' in the where.

Changing the query in the method from `where type = 'plugin'` to `where a.type = 'plugin'`, which makes sense since this is a joined list, and this way the type field is referencing its table, the issue is gone.

Has anyone notice this kind of issue with the com_plugins?

Comment: Could you also confirm you MySQL version?

Comment: @Lodder: MySQL 5.5.36 on the live server and also 5.5.29 on my localost.

Answer (score 1):

For aliasing a table, you replace your current code:

```
->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions') . ' AS a')
```

with:

```
->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions', 'a'))
```

This will automatically generate `AS a`.

Now seeing that you're using an alias, you need to replace:

```
->where($db->quoteName('type')
```

with:

```
->where($db->quoteName('a.type')
```

Comment: The thing is that it's not me that is using it, but it's in the core.

Comment: Can you check your joomla plugins model file line 211 and tell me what you see there?

Comment: Yup, will do in a bit

Comment: @FFrewin - It's the same as as the code you've provided but I don't seems to get any errors. Try going to **Extensions** >> **Extensions Manager** >> **Database** and see if there is anything to fix. I have tried setting my error reporting to maximum and my MySQL version is 5.5.24 which is close to yours but I don't get any errors

Comment: I have done so (fixing database)... I also don't get any errors on any other Joomla. Even on this website everything was ok a few days ago.

Comment: Have any changes been made to the site? Such as new extensions or any file changes?

Comment: Something else worth noting is that other where clauses in the same query are written by referencing the aliased table... check the a few more lines down the query.

Comment: I saw. It might be worth pointing out on Github just in case it's a bug

Comment: I was unable to create an item for this in JTracker. It gives me an error (can't remember the error now). Any idea why?

Comment: I don't have any participation in adding issues or in Joomla CMS in general so unfortunately have the foggiest :/

Comment: 2 years later - even now with J3.6.4 I am still getting this same error in com_plugins for this particular site. How strange...(?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to confirm that this one site DID NOT have a `type` column in the `#__users` and/or `#__viewlevels` tables?

The only possible cause that I can fathom is that one (or both, but I doubt it) of those tables gained a `type` column as an unintended fluke of development.  Is there any chance that you loaded an extension that made a change to one of these core tables?

The **ambiguous column error** can only be generated as a result of multiple tables containing the same column.

As Lodder has stated, the way to alleviate the error without altering the database is to make explicit declarations of the table name (or table alias) from which the target column belongs.

That said, because Joomla's core files are not written to nominate a tablename before the `type` column, it would be advisable to seek out the table with the extra `type` column (save a backup of the table), remove the rogue `type` column from the table, then run everything and see what breaks when the unexpected column is missing.  This forensic process will be integral in discovering the source of the issue.  Then again, if nothing breaks after removing the column, then the cause will be a mystery, but then the error should be permanently removed.